# How To Append Vector Of Row Sums Using Let Function In Excel

Tags: excel-formula

My question is two parts:

1. Is there a way to return a vector of the row sums of a data frame using the `LET` function?
2. Can one return this column appended to the original data frame in the same function?

For example, given the below data, I want to return the full data frame along with the column c(6, 15, 24).

[image]

I guess the first order of business is getting each individual row, but I have struggled so far. I've tried a couple things like `=LET(x, $A$1:$C$3, INDEX(x, ROW($A$1:$A$3), 0))` or  `=LET(x, $A$1:$C$3, y, ROW($A$1:$A$3), INDEX(x, y,y))` but no dice. Any tricks? Maybe the `CHOOSE` function could come in handy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=LET( data, A1:C3,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(--data,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0))))`
[image]
By multiplying all the values of one row with 1 per row using MMULT you can avoid SUM and INDEX. The result is a spilled sum result already that can be transposed.

Without LET: `=TRANSPOSE(MMULT(--A1:C3,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(A1:C3),1,1,0)))`

Not sure if you're u wanted to include the data set in the result; in that case you could use: `=LET( data, A1:C3,drows,ROWS(data),sum,TRANSPOSE(MMULT(--data,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0))),IF(SEQUENCE(drows+1)<=drows,data,sum))`
[image]

I just figured you would want it to be added as a column rather than a row (makes more sense too): `=LET( data, A1:C3,dcolumns,COLUMNS(data),sum,MMULT(--data,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0)),IF(SEQUENCE(1,dcolumns+1)<=dcolumns,data,sum))`
[image]

Aesthetic improvement showing blanks as blanks and zeroes as zeroes in the spill of the original range:
`=LET( data, A1:C3,dcolumns,COLUMNS(data),sum,MMULT(--data,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0)),IF(SEQUENCE(1,dcolumns+1)<=dcolumns,IF(LEN(data)<>0,data,""),sum)`

Comment: I wonder if Mark F. would be able to make it work using INDEX so it would work for - for instance - AVERAGE function as well.

Comment: Note to self: `=LET( data, A1:C3,dcolumns,COLUMNS(data),average,MMULT(--data,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0))/dcolumns,IF(SEQUENCE(1,dcolumns+1)<=dcolumns,data,average))` would be for AVERAGE provided that all fields contain data.

Comment: `=LET( data, A1:E3,dcolumns,COLUMNS(data),sum,MMULT(--data,SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(data),1,1,0)),UsedColumns,MMULT(SIGN(data),SEQUENCE(dcolumns,,,0)),IF(SEQUENCE(1,dcolumns+1)<=dcolumns,IF(LEN(data)<>0,data,""),sum/UsedColumns))` Average taking into account the number of used cells per row and showing `0` if a value is actual `0` and showing nothing when value is BLANK. Used that in my answer as improvement as well